# Displaying HTML table content dynamically

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

There is an issue that I could not figure out in this code. 
It should iterate of the array objects and display them in an HTML table. The third row should contain buttons. Why it does not show me anything?

HTML code:

```
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
<table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Level</th>
<th>Action</th>
</tr>

<tr id="table-rows">
<td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
<td>
    <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select> 
</td>
<td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" id="add-button"></td>
</tr>

</table>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="myscript.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript:

```
var myArray = [{"name":"aaa","level":"A"},{"name":"bbb","level":"B"},{"name":"ccc","level":"C"}];


display();
function display() {
        var length = myArray.length;
        var htmltext = "";

        for (var i = 1; i < length; i++) {
            htmltext += 
            "<tr id='row"+i+"'>\
                <td>"+myArray[i].name+"</td>\
                <td>"+myArray[i].level+"</td>\
                <td>\
                    <input type='button' id='edit_button"+i+"' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row("+i+")'> \
                    <input type='button' id='save_button"+i+"' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row("+i+")'> \
                    <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row("+i+")'>\
                </td>\
            </tr>";
        }
        document.getElementById("table-rows").innerHTML = htmltext;
    }
```

Comment: You append inside "table-rows" which is a row itself so you have rows in your rows which is not what you want, add a `<tbody>` and add to that if you want to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reference the table body with an ID, and also, your for loop should init i at 0, so you can traverse the whole array.

```js
var myArray = [{
  "name": "aaa",
  "level": "A"
}, {
  "name": "bbb",
  "level": "B"
}, {
  "name": "ccc",
  "level": "C"
}];


display();

function display() {
  var length = myArray.length;
  var htmltext = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    htmltext +=
      "<tr id='row" + i + "'>\
                <td>" + myArray[i].name + "</td>\
                <td>" + myArray[i].level + "</td>\
                <td>\
                    <input type='button' id='edit_button" + i + "' value='Edit' class='edit' onclick='edit_row(" + i + ")'> \
                    <input type='button' id='save_button" + i + "' value='Save' class='save' onclick='save_row(" + i + ")'> \
                    <input type='button' value='Delete' class='delete' onclick='delete_row(" + i + ")'>\
                </td>\
            </tr>";
  }
  document.getElementById("table-rows").innerHTML = htmltext;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="wrapper">
    <table align='center' cellspacing=2 cellpadding=5 id="data_table" border=1>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>Name</th>
          <th>Level</th>
          <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody id="table-rows">
        <tr>
          <td><input type="text" id="new_name"></td>
          <td>
            <select name="levels-list" id="levels-list">
    <option value="A" id="option-1">A</option>
    <option value="B" id="option-2">B</option>
    <option value="C" id="option-3">C</option>
    </select>
          </td>
          <td><input type="button" class="add" value="Add Row" id="add-button"></td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
document.getElementById("table-rows").innerHTML = htmltext;
```

Try to

```
document.getElementById("table-rows").append(htmltext);
```

Comment: [Node.append()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ParentNode/append) does not parse the string.

Answer (score -2):

Use handlebars.
http://handlebarsjs.com/
I use it for dynamic tables myself. Plus its bad practice to insert html with js.